# Using nested protobuf messages with Clickhouse Kafka engine

Tags: apache-kafka, protocol-buffers, clickhouse

I'm trying to use Clickhouse Kafka engine with source messages decoded to protobuf. I'm going to use nested schema, but faced with this issue. Here's my code:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

message Product {
  string model = 1;
  float price = 2;
}

message TestProto {
  string name = 1;
  Product product = 2;
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_table
(
    `name` String,
    `product` Nested(
        `model` String,
        `price` Float32
    )

)
ENGINE = Kafka
SETTINGS
    kafka_broker_list = 'kafka:9092',
    kafka_topic_list = 'test_proto_topic',
    kafka_group_name = 'test_proto_topic_ch',
    kafka_format = 'ProtobufSingle',
    format_schema = 'test.proto:TestProto'

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS target_table
(
    `name` String,
    `model` String,
    `price` Float32
)
ENGINE = Memory

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS target_table_view TO target_table
AS
SELECT
    `name`,
    `product.model` as model,
    `product.price` as price
FROM kafka_table
```

Everything works well except one thing - columns `model` and `price` doesn't filling with values from protobuf nested message `Product` and stored with default values.

How should I define tables correctly to make this works as expected?

Comment: according to
https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/15990#issuecomment-1859258504


try Array(Tuple(...))

Comment: Thank you for the link, I tried named tuple and it's decoded almost correctly, but I can't access to tuple's nested values, when I creating the materialized view like that: `name, product.model as model, product.price as price`
I see that error `DB::ExceptionDB::Exception: Missing columns: 'product.model' 'product.price'`
But if I define view with `toString(product)` I see, that all data in protobuf message decoded. So the problem is that I can not access nested tuple's fields in view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue, and there are two ways.
**First** is to create source kafka table with tuple:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_table
(
    `name` String,
    `product` Tuple(
        model String,
        price Float32
    )

)
...
```

It's named tuple, but you can not access to this fields via names, you need to use indexes:

```sql
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS target_table_view TO target_table
AS
SELECT
    name,
    product.1 as model,
    product.2 as price
FROM kafka_table
```

It's works, but I think it's not very convenient to use indexes, if your message has a lot of fileds.

**Second** is more easily:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS kafka_table
(
    name String,
    product_model String,
    product_price Float32
)
...
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS target_table_view TO target_table
AS
SELECT
    name,
    product_model as model,
    product_price as price
FROM kafka_table
```

Works like magic, here's the docs - https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/interfaces/formats#protobuf
Clickhouse tries to find all nested fields by itself and names it like 'x.y.z' or 'x_y_z'